# Facebook SDK for Unity slow settings screen

Tags: lag, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm using the Facebook SDK for Unity v5.04 (also tried 5.03) and whenever I open the FacebookSettings panel in the inspector I get ridiculous slowdown to the point that I can't even use Unity. This only happens when I do that, does anyone know what might be wrong? I've tried it on multiple computers now and all have been experiencing this lag.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting this same thing. I don't think this is happening to every project or the FB team would have noticed prior to pushing the builds out.

As far as I can tell, it only happens on larger projects. We have seen this same behavior in other plugins (namely one that one of our developers wrote) when the plugin tried to scan the project for a file of a specific name. It didn't show up in his tests but in large projects it made Unity almost unusable.

I tested the Facebook settings issue on a brand new project and it's fast.

**Potential Solution** Delete everything in your project except Facebook ;)

Edit: The settings menu appears to work just fine on a Mac. I have the same project on my PC and Mac (and the PC's specs are far better than the Mac's) yet it brings Unity to a crawl on the PC and it works fine on the Mac. Go figure :S

Answer (score 0):

OP: If you add the SDK to a new project, or Facebook's [sample project](https://github.com/fbsamples/friendsmash-unity), do you see the same issue? Also, could you update with the Unity version you're using, so we can explore? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem 
but when I follow this [Link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/616484/open-ssl-not-found.html) that solve "[Open SSL not found]" Problem >> The slow problem was disappeared.

this is the steps that I was follow:

1) Download and install OpenSSL. http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Win32 OpenSSL v#.#.# (not Light)

OR Win64 OpenSSL v#.#.# (not Light)

2) Add the OpenSSL directory to your path.

Go to: Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables

Select the Variable "Path" in the "System variables" window and click Edit.

3) Add the path to your OpenSSL bin folder to the end of the "Variable value" text. e.g. I added ";C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin" to the end of the value text.

Restart Unity3D.

take note do not forget to add semi-colon ";" before the C:/

4) If you get the error in FacebookSettings "Keytool not found", you need to add the JDK (Java Development Kit) bin directory to the Path variable value.

5) Follow the same steps as before, but instead of the OpenSSL bin path, add the JDK bin path. e.g. I added ";C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin" to the end of the value text.

Restart Unity3D.

Comment: Please refrain from link only answers. It is better to quote relevant text from the link in your answer.